Azure DevOps Tests - How do I hand over a running test case to another tester
I want to hand over a running test to another tester. But when the test is reopen via "Run", the test results from before are gone.

tested some of the tests in test case
assigned test to other tester
reopened test with context menu "Run -> Run for web application"


In the 'Run for web application' window in the upper right corner you can mark the test case result as paused. Now, you can press save and close the window.
In the test plan view on the execute tab you click on the three dots (More options) and select 'Assign tester' to select another tester to continue with the test.
This new tester now has the option 'Resume test'.
